# Build Apple TV app using Enterprise Apple Developer Account

Tags: objective-c, apple-tv

Our company has an "Enterprise Apple developer account" using which we are able to build, test & distribute (to different stake holders) iOS app successfully.

Now, we are working with Apple TV app and we are trying to build & archive using "Enterprise Apple developer account". We are able to build the app successfully, but we are not able to "export" such that we can generate ipa file and distribute it.

After archiving, we are able to see only 3 options as in attached image.
[image]

Can we build Apple TV apps using "Enterprise Apple Developer account"? or do we have to use Individual/company Apple developer account to build?

Comment: I think you should contact developer support team of Apple from your company Enterprise account.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm experiencing the exact same issue.